# How to mount the file into Jenkins docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to mount my file(/home/ubuntu/grace/new_project on ubuntu) into Jenkins Docker container and run 'nvidia-docker'. The directory that I want to copy it is in /var/jenkins_home/new_folder on Docker container.

This is the command to run Jenkins server using docker.

```
sudo docker run --rm \
-u root -p 8080:8080 \
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v "$HOME":/home   jenkinsci/blueocean
```

And I want to run this command in Jenkins.

```
sudo nvidia-docker run -d \
-v /home/ubuntu/grace:/notebooks/grace \
-it --name test classification:ver1.2
```

```
sudo nvidia-docker exec -it test python main.py
```

I expect my project (/home/ubuntu/grace/new_project) is in /var/jenkins_home/new_folder/ on docker container so that I can run 'nvidia-docker' to run 'main.py'.

My ultimate goal is to make Jenkins pipeline to run my project using 'sudo nvidia-docker exec -it auto python main.py' from shell script.
 Anybody can help me?

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I want to run exec command through Jenkins pipeline script. How can I run those 'sudo nvidia-docker exec -it test python main.py' command through Jenkins?